# Why is it necessary to know a state of a system?

Tags: control, state-space

In a system why is necessary ? why cant we use a simple transfer funtion in an S or Z domain ,to get an input output relation , or as we already know our input and measure our outputs through sensors ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the system has memory, you need to know what state the memory is in. For example: a system with a low pass filter of a resistor and a capacitor will respond differently if the capacitor is fully charged or if the capacitor starts with zero voltage. The system will respond differently depending on the *initial conditions or state*

It isn't simply enough to know how a system will respond, but you also need to know what state it is in *now* to determine it's future behavior

Another example of this is useful for analyzing the circuit. If you zero out the state and only consider the input this is called "Zero-State" analysis. 
Conversely, if you zero out the input and supply a state, it's called "Zero-Input" analysis.

[image]
Source: [Dummies Find the response](http://www.dummies.com/education/science/science-electronics/find-the-total-response-of-a-series-rc-circuit/)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes we have systems where a transfer function representation, called an external description, is insufficient to completely characterize it. As an example consider the circuit below, taken for the most part from Lathi's Principles of Linear Systems and Signals.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCsEzI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Where out input is x(t) on the left and let's take our ouput across the two resistors on the right. Let's also put some initial charge across the capacitor, which results in currents due to it.

As the system is linear we can find the total response as the sum of the zero-input and zero-state responses. To find the zero-input response we would set x(t) to zero and compute currents due to the capacitor, if you do this you will find it has no effect on the output y(t).

The zero-state response can be found by setting the initial capacitor charge to zero and doing the circuit analysis. You will find that the problem reduces to a simple voltage divider.

I have skipped the actual analysis as the important point here is that no external measurement of the output and input can possibly tell you what the current through the capacitor is.

This is for the most part a toy problem but it illustrates that the state of a system is not fully specified by its transfer function. In some cases this could be very important as something dangerous or unstable may be happening inside the system.

Additionally, transfer functions are limited to systems with a single input and a single output. If you are interested, look up controlability and observability of systems. This will give you some more detail about when it is important to have a state, or internal, description of a system.

Answer (score 1):

1) when you consider a state feedback controller

2) when linear system theory can not be applied ( nonlinear systems)

3)when you don‘t have a sensor for the state you are interested in (estimators)

4) when you have to optimize a state dependent objective function

5) design of tracking applications

6) need to consider initial conditions

7) complex problems are easier to handle in the time domain

...

Comment: you can have non-zero initial conditions in transfer function.

Comment: @CroCo : I agree that this is possible, however, this is normally not performed. At least in the usual control design methods ICs are not taken account. I think the state space approach is better suited in this regard. Isn’t it?

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I'm not sure I understand your question, but I'll try conceptually explaining my *interpretation* of your question: why do we measure the state of systems in a controls problem?

---

Controls is fundamentally about changing states, so **how can you change something's state or behavior if you don't know how it currently behaves?**

For example, you act as a controller when you watch TV. You sit down to watch TV, but you *see* (eyes = sensor) that the TV (plant) is "OFF" (state). You *press* (actuation or control input) the power button on your remote to *switch* the TV "ON" (change in state). **How could you have activated the TV without knowing its current state with your eyes?**

You can have the most complex transfer function that relates the depth of the remote control's buttons to the strength of the remote's IR beam to ... to the pixel intensity of each pixel, but all of that is useless if you don't know the current state of the buttons or TV! Was the TV already ON or OFF? Was the power button previously pressed? If the TV is ON and you just pressed the power button, then you just turned OFF the TV!

Even the most advanced robust and optimal digital controller with Kalman filtering needs to *sample* (observe) a system every now and then with *some* sensors to get an idea of what's going on. We assume many simplifications and ignore many complex processes when developing control algorithms, so we can rarely make an open-loop controller that can handle 100% of the requested tasks.

For example, let's say you had the *exact* transfer function for controlling the position of an RC car from a joystick's movements, even including the mechanical transients of the wheels. You close your eyes (no sensors, no knowledge of the state), and you start giving different inputs. Suddenly, a little kid comes in, picks up the car, and moves it somewhere else. **Is the car where your transfer function says it is if an external actor disturbed your perfect math?** You need some sort of feedback on the actual state.